# Can Mono Gendarme run on source files?

Tags: mono, gendarme

I understood that tool only runs on .net assemblies. Is there any way to make it run on source files instead ? Even if it requires source modification , i would like to know the possibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't. The way it works is by inspecting the IL code from the compiled binary, so source code modifications wouldn't help.
It's not a significant limitation, anyway (if you make heavy use of conditionals you will want to run it on the binaries built with the different flags).